# LTspice, how to model a TLine

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to do a simulation for a transmission line, I can draw below example circuit but got below two questions.

1. How to do this step: `.model TLine LTRA(...)`

It looks to define the component property and should I do it in "component attribute editor" but it doesn't work.

2. The 50 ohms impedance is based on the calculation SQRT(L/C), there is no column to specify this value, right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press 'S' and add the `SPICE` directive `.model MyLtline ltline L=<...> C=<...> len=<...>` etc (as needed, `L`, `C` and `len` should be minimum) and place it in your schematic. For this you'll have to modify `ltline` with `MyLtline` (case insensitive).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, thank you and it works now! btw, may I know what is the unit for LEN (inch??)? I google and found the units for RLCG but not LEN.    Thank you! 
        http://techdocs.altium.com/display/AMSE/LTRA+-+Lossy+Transmission+Line+Model#

Comment: It's in meters. If you want a one inch length, you would write `0.0254`, or `25.4m` (`25m4` is also accepted).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, thank you so much for your kind help!! It helps a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can call a model TLINE but maybe you can.
You should not enter units. Let's call the model 'myTline':
.model myTline LTRA(R=10m L=9n C=3.59p len=1)
R/L/C are parameters for a piece of wire of '1' length (if R/L/C values describe Ohms/Henries/Farads per meter then len of 1 is 1 meter).
So if you want double the length you set it to 2 etc.

Then you just fill the 'Value' in LTRA component properties to be 'myTline', don't fill the other fields.